# compilation errors when using glsaddall

Tags: pdftex, glossaries, xindy

When I compile the example below I got the error:

```
! undefined control sequence
<write> (indexentry :tkey (\glo@computer@index) : locref "{}{\gls@numberpage}"...
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,dvipsnames]{report}
\usepackage[style=long,toc,xindy,acronym, sort=use]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{computer}{
    name=computer,
    description={is a programmable machine that receives input, stores and manipulates data, and provides output in a useful format}}
\begin{document}
 \glsaddall
 \printglossaries
\end{document}
```

If I add `gls{computer}` the example compile without error. 
How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This works. You need to use the entries defined in the glossary. Otherwise there is no way to sort them!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[style=long,toc,acronym,xindy,sort=use]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{computer}{
    name=computer,
    description={is a programmable machine that receives input, stores and manipulates data, and provides output in a useful format}}
\newglossaryentry{comp}{
    name=comp,
    description={is a programmable machine that receives input, stores and manipulates data, and provides output in a useful format}}


\begin{document}

\noindent
\gls{computer}\\
\gls{comp}

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

If you don't want to use `\gls{}` and use `\glsaddall{}` instead, remove `sort=use` from the package options.

Comment: But I don't want to use them that's why I used `glsaddall`

Comment: So remove `sort=use` and everything will work.

Comment: Please mention that in your answer, if no other answer that doesn't require removing `sort=use` is provided, I will accept yours.